# Effective select data from big table with order by datetime

Tags: mysql

How can you optimize obtain 10 last records from big table (500 thousands records).
In sql query is not used any index, because there is not where part. So you have just order by datetime (DESC) and limit. Such query durate 4 second. Is any faster way?

```
SELECT * FROM `big_table` ORDER BY `create_date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious index to add here would be on the `create_date` column:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON big_table (create_date);
```

This would allow the sorting of the records in the table to happen in logarithmic time, instead of linear time, the latter which would be the performance sans index using a table scan.

If you knew the columns you were selecting and could avoid a `SELECT *`, then you could add those columns to the tail of the index, e.g.

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON big_table (create_date, col1, col2);
```

for selecting two columns only.

Comment: Really. It never occurred to me that there could be an index on datetime. Thank you.